# conversion table from feet and inches to cm

Tags: c, loops

I need to write a program which prints the conversion table from feet and inches to centimetres. The numbers printed in row `i` (counting from zero), column `j` (counting from zero) of the table should be the cm equivalent of `i` feet and `j` inches. `i` should go from 0 to 7, and `j` from 0 to 11. Each column should be five characters wide, and the cm figures should be rounded to the nearest integer.

The example of required output is given below:

```
     0 3 5 8 10 13 
    30 33 36 38 41 
    61 64 66 69 71 
    91 94 97 99 102
```

The code I have prints only one row of inches and column of feet but I don't know how to make into table without producing lots of irrelevant repetitions.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int cm,p;
    for (i=0; i<= 11; i++) {
        cm =round(i * 2.54);
        printf ("%5d",cm);
    }

    for (j=0; j<=7; j++) {
        p =round(j* 12.0 * 2.54);
        printf ("%5d\n",p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This produces:

```
    0    3    5    8   10   13   15   18   20   23   25   28    0
   30
   61
   91
  122
  152
  183
  213
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Inches rounded to integer cm?? That's awfully imprecise!

Comment: Your life will be much better if you name your variables the same as your verbiage.  And, btw, I would recommend feet and inches as opposed to i & j.

Comment: @olaf - Might be just a male thing?

Comment: @EdHeal: That was not my thought. But rounding 2.54cm up adds quite an error.

Comment: @olaf - That was kinda my point (or humour)

Answer (score 2):

You have one loop after the other.  What you need to do is run through the inches loop *every iteration of your feet loop*.  What you get is **nested loops**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (int feet = 0;  feet <= 7;  ++feet) {
        for (int inches = 0;  inches < 12;  ++inches) {
            int microns = (feet * 12 + inches) * 25400;
            int rounded_cm = (microns + 5000) / 10000;
            printf("%5d", rounded_cm);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

I've made some other changes in my version; you're encouraged to study it and understand why it does what it does (read the man page for `puts()`, for example).  Don't just copy it and hand it in - it will be obvious it isn't your code.

---

An alternative approach is to use a single loop (in inches), and insert a newline when we reach the 11th inch in each foot:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0;  i < 96;  ++i) {
        printf("%4d%s",
               (i * 25400 + 5000) / 10000,
               i%12==11 ? "\n" : " ");
    }
}
```

(You'll want to give meaningful names to your constants; the above is written in a "code-golf" style).

---

Whatever you do, don't be tempted to avoid multiplying by instead adding 2.54 repeatedly in the loop.  Floating-point numbers are not exact, and addition will accumulate the error.

Comment: I am afraid your answer is wrong. Your program is doing too much rounding off. E.g. it will print 2 ft = 61 CMs instead of 60 CMs or 3 ft = 91 CMs instead of 90 CMs.

Comment: 2ft == 60.8 cm, which rounds to 61.

Comment: @VHS [2 feet is 60.96 cm](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=%3D+60.96+centimeters&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and "cm figures should be rounded to the nearest integer" --> 61 cm.

Comment: Er yes, 60.96, not 60.8.  The code is correct, if not my comment!

Answer (score 2):

OP needs to put the "inches" loop inside the "foot" loop as well answered by others. [@Toby Speight](/a/41001994) [@VHS](/a/41001169)

Code could do its "round to nearest" via the `printf()` statement by using `"%5.0f"` to control the output width and rounding.

Let code use `foot/inch` instead of `i/j` [@KevinDTimm](/users/54200) for clarity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define INCH_PER_FOOT 12
#define CM_PER_INCH 2.54

int main(void) {
  // go from 0 to 7, and ...
  for (int foot = 0; foot <= 7; foot++) {
    // from 0 to 11
    // for (int inch = 0; inch < INCH_PER_FOOT; inch++) { is more idiomatic
    for (int inch = 0; inch <= 11; inch++) {
      printf("%5.0f", (foot * INCH_PER_FOOT + inch) * CM_PER_INCH);
    }
    puts("");
  }
}
```

Output

```
    0    3    5    8   10   13   15   18   20   23   25   28
  ...
  213  216  218  221  224  226  229  231  234  236  239  241
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running your loops backwards. First you need to run through feet and then through inches. But you are having it the other way round. Check the following snipped and compare it with your code and try to understand what's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> // for rounding of a number
int main()
{
 int i,j;
 int cm,p;
 for(i=0; i<=7;i++) {
     for(j=0;j<=11;j++) {
         cm = round(i*30.48 + j*2.54);
         printf ("%5d",cm);
     }
     printf("\n");
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `<math.h>` since C99 has `long int lround(double x)` that rounds and converts to an integer type in one function call vs. `double round(double x)` which causes the addition to be done in FP math, along with a final `double` to `int` conversion.  Still good answer.

Comment: `i*30`?  Really?  Or is that merely sabotage?

Comment: @TobySpeight, `i*30` is there because 1 foot has 30 centimeters.

Comment: Hmm, as per Google Calculator, 1 ft is indeed 30.48 cms. I thought 1 ft equated to 30.00 cms exactly. I have updated my answer to use 30.48 instead of 30. Good catch guys.